# React Native "TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body."

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My code:

```js
saveBarcod() {

    var email = 'skarakas';
    var password = 'skarakas';

    fetch(
      '***********/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCRM_TEST01_SRV/DataSet',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization : 'Basic c2thcmFrYXM6NjU0MzIx',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          Key: '1',
          Type : 'asd',
          Value : 'sdf'
        }),
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        alert('hello1');
      })
      .then((responseData) => {
        alert('hello2');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      })
      .done();
}
```

Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Question 1 : how to add username and password to fetch ?

Question 2 :  I tried below code but not solve my problem.

```js
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'Key': '1',
          'Type' : 'asd',
          'Value' : 'sdf'
        }),
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Tip: code blocks are created using **backticks** `\``, not single quotes `'`

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1 : how to add username and password to fetch ?

It depends how the server expects authentication. You are already sending an `Authorization` header, which probably was constructed hashing somehow user/password or by sending a previous request to server and getting its response.

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

This error cannot be from the code you posted, as yours is not a `GET` nor a `HEAD` (which have to be `body` free), but a `POST` (because of the `method: 'POST'` in your request, which can have a `body`).